# How to simplify this binomial coefficients?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

For $a, b, r, n \in \mathbb N$ :
I have to simplify

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{r}\binom {a}k\binom {b}{r-k}$$

I tried by using factorials but it seemed more complicated

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use that, by definition, $\dbinom nk$ is the coefficients of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$. So here, consider the expansion of each side  in the equality  and compare the coefficients of $x^r$:
$$(1+x)^a(1+x)^b=(1+x)^{a+b}.$$

Comment: thank you I'm going to try

Comment: @Lamethyste: I've added a detail to the hint.

Comment: $(1+X)^r=(1+X)^{a+b}$, so 

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{r}\binom {r}kX^k=\sum_{k = 0}^{r}(\sum_{i = 0}^{k}\binom {a}i\binom {b}{k-i})X^k$$

So for k=r :$\binom {r}rX^r$=$\sum_{i = 0}^{r}\binom {a}r\binom {b}{r-i}X^r$, knowing that $\binom {r}r=1$

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{r}\binom {a}k\binom {b}{r-k}=1$$

Comment: I didn't suggest to expand $(1+x)^r$ but to calculate the coefficient of $x^r$ in both sides (which  ultimately use the expansion of $(1+x)^{a+b}$). Anyway, a sum of binomial coefficients can't be equal to $1$, unless there is only one term, equal to $1$.

Comment: sorry I could not answer you, but i think that I found something better, thank you for your help

Comment: A combinatorial proof?